# Activity is restarted when a phone call is received

Tags: android

I have an activity which is basically a tabbed activity for keeping a score a of cards game.

The problem is that, when I get phone call and  I come back to my app, then the score is cleared!

It seems like activity is restarted a phone called is received. Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android devices had limited memory, and can only run so many apps at once. Phone calls are one of the most taxing tasks on a mobile's hardware, as audio streams aren't exactly small on memory usage.

Due to this, I think your app's current instance is killed to free up RAM, and this results in a loss of scores for you.

To fix this, you could write the value of the scores to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in your Activity's `onPause()` and then retrieve them in `onResume()`.

Comment: hmm thats great to know and  I like the suggestion

Comment: Is there a way I can make app restarts from a certain activity when this happens? I mean if Activity starts Activity B and during activity B, I get a phone call. How can I make the app come back to Activity A to restart the whole thing?

Comment: Doing things that way would present a poor user experience. You want to save out any info you need to restore the activity's state to make it look to the user like your app was never restarted.